# flexslider different animationSpeed for some slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slideshow, flexslider

i have a problem with the loading of the first slide on the page, then i would like to set the animationSpeed to '0' , only for the first slide. There's a way to do it ?

this is my flexslider-init.js

```
(function($) {
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: 'fade',
        easing: 'linear',
        slideshowSpeed: 7000,
        animationSpeed: 1000
    });
});
})(jQuery)
```

thank you

Comment: why not just use `startAt` to start at the second slide?

Comment: i want to show the first slide, but just more fastly.